# Natty freezes constantly after install

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-11.04

I've just installed 11.04 and now at random everything freezes. The keyboard responds but the only thing that seems to unlock it is a reisub. I never had this problem before and I've had this computer for almost a year. I'm using gnome 3 but it also happens when I'm using unity. Even if I don't have any programs running soon or later it freezes. I've seen some similar questions here like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171357/what-do-do-when-linux-gui-freezes) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/280028/ubuntu-natty-desktop-freezes-after-login) but no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a sync issue (which I thought they'd already patched).
Try this and see if it helps:

Grab the compiz settings manager like so:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it up and browse to the openGL plug-in.

Look for the "Sync to VBlank" option and uncheck it.

Comment: I already had the compiz manager. just unchecked the vblank box.

Comment: by now it would have froze 4 or 5 times :) thnx

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. It turns out in my case that the r8169 networking module was unstable. Uninstalling the vanilla r8169 module Using the [Realtek proprietary r8168 module](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8168E/RTL8111F) solved this for me. I have no problems with stability now.